# python regex match with words in between as optional

Tags: python, regex

I have different regex patterns with a lot of optional parts in it, but it doesn't work:

```
import re

s = 'not something useful at all'

p=re.compile(r'not (?:so)? (useful|good|correct)')

if p.search(s) != None:
    print(p.search(s).group(0))
else:
    print("no match")
```

so if i execute this i get the "no match" printed but if i change 'something' to 'so' then i get printed "not so useful" the 'so' part is optional meaning if it is not there, then "not" and "useful" should still match

also another pattern match i need is something like:

```
import re

s = 'not random_text_inbetween useful random_text_inbetween at random_text_inbetween all'

p=re.compile(r'(not|maybe) (?:so)? (useful|good|correct) (?:at)? (?:all)?')

if p.search(s) != None:
    print(p.search(s).group(0))
else:
    print("no match")
```

Edit: ok so i will rephrase the question for the second part here:

wiktor provided this regex `(not|maybe)(?:(?: so)?.*?)? (useful|good|correct)(?: at(?: all)?)?`

this marks on this regex 101 website the following matches:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-32    `not random_text_inbetween useful`
Group 1.    0-3 `not`
Group 2.    26-32   `useful`
```

but what i also need are matches/groups in case one or more of the optional parts are also in the string:

> "not random_text_inbetween useful random_text_inbetween **at**
>   random_text_inbetween **all**"

so in this example i would like to have a group for "at" , "all" because they appear in the text above.

if the optional parts are not found then these groups should simply not be returned but only the remaining matches for the mandatory words like "not" , "useful"

Comment: How do you define a pattern for optional parts? A streak of non-whitespace, word or any chars? Check https://regex101.com/r/ewS8q7/1

Comment: hello wiktor thanks but this gives me only a match for "not" and "useful" the optional parts are not marked as "match" instead the "random_text_inbetween" is marked as a match which i dont want

Comment: for example the optional words "at" and "all" are not marked as a match

Comment: If you explain what "not marked as a match" phrase means, and what you need in particular, you might get help here.

Comment: this regex 101 website shows me the group 1 : 'not' and group 2: 'useful' but the missing groups are for 'at' and 'all' i dont see them on the right side where it display "Match Information"

Comment: also i tried the regex you provided with this text : "not so useful at all" and it shows again only group 1 : 'not' and group 2: 'useful' but no group for 'so'

Comment: Please add the details to the question.

Comment: i did add the details is it clear now ? or should i modify the question again?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I remove the close and down vote. If I have time, I will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out now :-)

with this regex:

```
(not) (?:[^|]+) (useful) (?:[^|]+) (at)? (?:[^|]+) (all)?
```

i am able to capture what i want. thanks wiktor for helping me and providing this regex online website which is really helpful to quickly test your regex patterns.